# How to save and reload automatically in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

This is my first question so please help me !
Here's the problem, I want to execute the following commands every 1 or 2 seconds. Maybe using the timer control but I don't know how to do it.
I am making a HTML tester and it is working but I have to click the button to execute this command. I want it to happen automatically, the saving of file and refreshing the Web Browser.

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
sb.AppendLine(RichTextBox1.Text)
IO.File.WriteAllText("htmltester.html", sb.ToString())
WebBrowser1.Navigate("file:///" & IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\htmltester.html"))
```

Thanks. If you think I posted a wrong code then please tell me how can I post a good question ! :)

Answer (score 2):

try using timer.
 using timer_tick with your very the same code

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
         Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    sb.AppendLine(RichTextBox1.Text)
    IO.File.WriteAllText("htmltester.html", sb.ToString())
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("file:///" & IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\htmltester.html"))
 End Sub
```

set your timer interval in how many seconds to you want under your properties window.

Hope that help you and you get the idea

Comment: Will it execute it every second or two ?

Comment: if that works please mark it as the correct answer :D thanks